# Using product position not working for display priority

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I'm trying to Display all products from my store to given position. I did change and set position from category products under manage category section.

This is my category structure.

```
Root category(0)
     Man(10)
        Shirt(5)
        Jeans(5)
     Women(10)    
        Shirt(5)
        Jeans(5)
```

Now my problem is given position is not working for root category(Man, Women). Its working ok for all subcategories. Anyone can help me how to solve this problem? My magento ver is 1.6
Thanks,

Comment: Here is an explanation on how the positions are calculated for products in anchor categories. http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7501/146

Comment: Thanks Marius,
But a can't understand how i can solve my problem.

Comment: It doesn't that's why I didn't write it as an answer. It just shows you why it doesn't work. You can try to change the algorithm for setting the positions in anchor categories. Maybe this helps: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8863/146

Comment: I checked this solution, but still not getting any result.